# NF-e 3.10 sefaz MG como faço para receber o retorno do NfeAutorizacaoLoteAsybc?

Tags: vb.net

Estou tentando dessa maneira (assincrono), com o sincrono eu também não consigo capturar nenhum status ou retorno, mas pelo menos transmite a nota para sefaz de MG

```
With NfeRecepcaoMG
    .Url = "https://nfe.fazenda.mg.gov.br/nfe2/services/NfeAutorizacao?wsdl"
    .nfeCabecMsgValue = xCabecalho2
    .Timeout = 50000
    .ClientCertificates.Add(cert)
    .SoapVersion = Web.Services.Protocols.SoapProtocolVersion.Soap12
    .NfeAutorizacaoLoteAsync(NfeRecepcaoMGmsg)
End With
```

Answer (score 1):

Você não está pegando o retorno do Webservice. Tente o seguinte:

```
Option Infer On

With NfeRecepcaoMG
    .Url = "https://nfe.fazenda.mg.gov.br/nfe2/services/NfeAutorizacao?wsdl"
    .nfeCabecMsgValue = xCabecalho2
    .Timeout = 50000
    .ClientCertificates.Add(cert)
    .SoapVersion = Web.Services.Protocols.SoapProtocolVersion.Soap12
End With

Dim retorno = NfeRecepcaoMG.NfeAutorizacaoLoteAsync(NfeRecepcaoMGmsg)
```